# Why are the results different for training and inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am training reinforcement learning using the double DQN algorithm.

The goal is to turn a two-dimensional board filled with zeros into ones.

For training to be successful, the model needs to find the target about 10 times in a row.

Then saved and loaded the trained model to run the inference process.

However, during the inference process, the model failed miserably.

I ran 100 episodes and it didn't succeed even once.

Is there a solution?

The code below changed the ENV and model structure of the code in the Pytorch tutorial.

tutorial link : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html

```
import gymnasium as gym
import math
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import os

from collections import namedtuple, deque

os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

Transition = namedtuple('Transition',
                        ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward'))

class ReplayMemory(object):
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.memory = deque([], maxlen=capacity)

    def push(self, *args):
        self.memory.append(*args)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)

class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_observations, n_actions):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(n_observations, 512)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.layer4 = nn.Linear(256, n_actions)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(inputs))
        x = F.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer3(x))
        return self.layer4(x)

class CustomEnv(gym.Env):   
    def __init__(self, max_x, max_y):
        self.max_x = max_x
        self.max_y = max_y
    
    def reset(self):
        self.board = np.full((self.max_y, self.max_x), 0)        
        self.n_same = 0

        return self.board

    def step(self, action):
        reward = 0
        done = False
        
        tile_type = action % 2
        temp = action // 2

        y = temp // self.max_x
        x = temp % self.max_x

        if self.board[y][x] != tile_type: 
            self.board[y][x] = tile_type 

            if tile_type == 1 :
                self.n_same += 1
                reward = 1

                if self.n_same == self.max_y * self.max_x:
                    reward = 100
                    done = True
            else : 
                self.n_same -= 1
                reward = -1

        return self.board, reward, done
    
BATCH_SIZE = 128
GAMMA = 0.99
EPS_START = 0.9
EPS_END = 0.05
EPS_DECAY = 1000
TAU = 0.005
LR = 1e-4
SEED = 42

np.random.seed(SEED)

env = CustomEnv(9, 7)

find_device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
state = env.reset()
n_observations = env.max_x * env.max_y
action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(n_observations * 2)

policy_net = DQN(n_observations, action_space.n).to(find_device)
target_net = DQN(n_observations, action_space.n).to(find_device)
target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())

optimizer = optim.AdamW(policy_net.parameters(), lr=LR, amsgrad=True)
memory = ReplayMemory(10000)

steps_done = 0

def select_action(state):
    global steps_done
    sample = random.random()
    eps_threshold = EPS_END + (EPS_START - EPS_END) * \
        math.exp(-1. * steps_done / EPS_DECAY)
    steps_done += 1
    if sample > eps_threshold:
        with torch.no_grad():
            return policy_net(state).max(1)[1].view(1, 1)
    else:
        return torch.tensor([[action_space.sample()]], device=find_device, dtype=torch.long)

episode_durations = []

def optimize_model():
    if len(memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
        return
    transitions = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
    batch = Transition(*zip(*transitions))

    non_final_mask = torch.tensor(tuple(map(lambda s: s is not None,
                                          batch.next_state)), device=find_device, dtype=torch.bool)
    non_final_next_states = torch.cat([s for s in batch.next_state
                                                if s is not None])
    state_batch = torch.cat(batch.state)
    action_batch = torch.cat(batch.action)
    reward_batch = torch.cat(batch.reward)
    state_action_values = policy_net(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)

    next_state_values = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE, device=find_device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        next_state_values[non_final_mask] = target_net(non_final_next_states).max(1)[0]
    expected_state_action_values = (next_state_values * GAMMA) + reward_batch

    criterion = nn.SmoothL1Loss()
    loss = criterion(state_action_values, expected_state_action_values.unsqueeze(1))

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(policy_net.parameters(), 100)
    optimizer.step()

def main() :
    running_Reward = 0

    for e in range(1000):
        e_reward = 0
        state = env.reset()
        tensor_state = torch.tensor(state.flatten(), dtype=torch.float32, device=find_device).unsqueeze(0)
        s = 0

        while True:
            action = select_action(tensor_state)
            observation, reward, done = env.step(action.item())
            reward = torch.tensor([reward], device=find_device)
            e_reward += reward.item()

            if done: 
                next_state = None

            else:
                next_state = torch.tensor(observation.flatten(), dtype=torch.float32, device=find_device).unsqueeze(0)

            memory.push(Transition(tensor_state, action, next_state, torch.tensor([reward], device=find_device)))
            tensor_state = next_state
            optimize_model()

            target_net_state_dict = target_net.state_dict()
            policy_net_state_dict = policy_net.state_dict()
            
            for key in policy_net_state_dict:
                target_net_state_dict[key] = policy_net_state_dict[key] * 0.005 + target_net_state_dict[key] * (1 - 0.005)
            target_net.load_state_dict(target_net_state_dict)

            s += 1
            if done or s >= 500: 
                running_Reward = running_Reward * (1 - 0.05) + float(e_reward) * 0.05   
                break

        if running_Reward > 155:
            print(f"Solved at episode {len(e_rewards)}!")
            break

        print(f"Reward for {e}th episode: {e_reward}")
    
    torch.save(policy_net.state_dict(), './testModel.pth')

def inference():
    policy_net.load_state_dict(torch.load('./testModel.pth', map_location=find_device))
    policy_net.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for e in range(100) :
            e_reward = 0
            state = env.reset()
            
            for _ in range(500) :
                tensor_state = torch.tensor(state.flatten(), dtype=torch.float32, device=find_device).unsqueeze(0)
                action = policy_net(tensor_state).max(1)[1].view(1, 1)
                state, r, done = env.step(action.item())
                e_reward += r

                if done :
                    break
                
            print(f"Reward for {e}th inference episode: {e_reward}")


Train = False

if Train:
    main()

else :
    inference()
```

Below is the sum of the rewards returned by the model in each episode towards the end of training.

A value of 162 means that the model found the correct answer in that episode.

```
Reward for 0th episode: 35
Reward for 1th episode: 38
Reward for 2th episode: 53
Reward for 3th episode: 50
Reward for 4th episode: 54
Reward for 5th episode: 54
Reward for 6th episode: 54
...
Reward for 443th episode: 162
Reward for 444th episode: 162
Reward for 445th episode: 162
Reward for 446th episode: 162
Reward for 447th episode: 162
Reward for 448th episode: 162
Reward for 449th episode: 162
Reward for 450th episode: 162
Reward for 451th episode: 162
Reward for 452th episode: 162
Solved at episode 453!
```

but result of inference

```
Reward for 0th episode: 6
Reward for 1th episode: 6
Reward for 2th episode: 6
Reward for 3th episode: 6
Reward for 4th episode: 6
Reward for 5th episode: 6
Reward for 6th episode: 6
Reward for 7th episode: 6
Reward for 8th episode: 6
Reward for 9th episode: 6
Reward for 10th episode: 6
...
```

I need help.
All comments are welcome.
thx.

Comment: Do you restart your script after training to switch to inference?

Comment: I print() the process of save and load the model's weight and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your answer to my comment is yes, I think I know the problem.
If you start your script with `Train=False`, the variable `steps_done` is also set to `0`. In `inference()`, you call
`action = select_action(tensor_state)`
which then calculates a high `eps_threshold` because of `steps_done = 0`. This leads most likely to a random action, and not one the trained `policy_net` would choose. At the end of training, the model has probably already taken 1000s of steps, so the `eps_threshold` is low and the probability to take an action from the `policy_net` is high.
I think you should disable the random action call at inference time. For example, in `select_action(state)` change

```
if sample > eps_threshold:
```

to

```
if sample > eps_threshold or not Train:
```

to always get the action from the `policy_net` at inference.

Comment: I already tried it and Failed.

Comment: This is print of inference.
Reward for 89th episode: 13
Reward for 90th episode: 13
Reward for 91th episode: 13
Reward for 92th episode: 13
Reward for 93th episode: 13
Reward for 94th episode: 13
Reward for 95th episode: 13
Reward for 96th episode: 13
Reward for 97th episode: 13
Reward for 98th episode: 13
Reward for 99th episode: 13

Comment: and I restart the script